# proguard-android-optimize.txt vs proguard-android.txt in Android build.gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle, proguard

I was reading [the docs about shrinking, obfuscating and optimising for a release build using build.gradle for an Android app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code). In one section of the docs, **`proguard-android.txt`** is used as the defauly ProGuard file:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

and in another section, **`proguard-android-optimize.txt`** is used:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be an explanation of what the difference between these are, and I can't find any information. Can someone explain what the differences are and when you would use **`proguard-android-optimize.txt`** vs **`proguard-android.txt`**?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Take a look at the Android source code over [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android-optimize.txt).

> Optimizations: If you don't want to optimize, use the
>   proguard-android.txt configuration file instead of this one, which
>   turns off the optimization flags.  Adding optimization introduces
>   certain risks, since for example not all optimizations performed by
>   ProGuard works on all versions of Dalvik.  The following flags turn
>   off various optimizations known to have issues, but the list may not
>   be complete or up to date. (The "arithmetic" optimization can be
>   used if you are only targeting Android 2.0 or later.)  Make sure you
>   test thoroughly if you go this route.

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35509428/7016022) is a pretty good read as well.

Comment: If you use R8, I think the optimisation file has no effect right? Reading https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#optimization `R8 ignores any ProGuard rules that attempt to modify default optimizations, such as -optimizations and - optimizationpasses`

Comment: @ErsenOsman Correct, although there are different manners to optimize for R8. For example: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#full-mode and https://jakewharton.com/blog/ has some posts on R8 Optimization.