# Android version release warning message: This App Bundle contains Java/Kotlin code, which might be obfuscated

Tags: android, google-play, release, obfuscation

I got this warning message:

> This App Bundle contains Java/Kotlin code, which might be obfuscated. We recommend you upload a deobfuscation file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug

what does it mean? what is the shortest solution for this?

Comment: your code could be obfuscated by proguard so any crash analysis systems could give unreadable logs and advises to create and upload a de-obfuscation file https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en

Comment: But I do already get good crash reports with accurate function names and line numbers. Can I just ignore this message then?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Seems like it's a warning message coming from the new play console, you can solve it just by setting your minimum api level to 29 or even better by uploading the retrace mapping file as described [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1008#issuecomment-682092997).
Enable minify :

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

After building apk/app bundle you can find `/app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt` file . New console will allow you to upload mapping.txt along with your apk or bundle. You can find this option from App bundles and APKs menus.(According to [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1008#issuecomment-682092997))

Comment: Goto the app in play console > App bundle explorer > On the top right click artifact and select the latest version that you just uploaded > Then go to downloads tab > Scroll down to assets tab > Upload it to "ReTrace mapping file" via the upload button on the right.

Comment: In my case (using Mac OS) mapping.txt located in build/app/outputs/mapping/r8/release/mapping.txt

Comment: I use flutter build apk

Comment: @SharifRafidUrRahman when i upload .aab and after i upload mapping.txt i have error/warning "You need to upload a valid .apk file.", i deleted mapping.txt and no have any warnings! Answer Rushabh work well) but i cant understand how(

Comment: @SharifRafidUrRahman should be included as the correct answer ty

Comment: @Fortran clean build. Rebuild. Increase version number then generate signed apk/aab then upload again with newly generated mapping text.

Comment: Thanks. Mine work by only changing minifyEnabled to true

Answer (score 22):

Just changing minifyEnabled to true worked for me

Comment: did you configure your proguard?

Answer (score 9):

You can solve this by just enabling minify in your build. gradle(app) file:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just enable minify in your build.gradle(app) file:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

proguard-android-optimize.txt sometimes is unsupported so using the following is safer (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902356/proguard-android-optimize-txt-vs-proguard-android-txt-in-android-build-gradle)):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But, after enabling "Minify enabled: true", many features like firebase authentications were not working properly. Not only firebase, but also other dependencies are not work properly after enabling this. I have tried it.
You can also once recheck it.

Comment: How does this answer the question?