# Playstore warnings: App Bundle contains native code, which can be deobfused & you have not uploaded any debugging symbols

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I know this question is asked before this as well and there are already some answers are available but still its not working for the ionic 4 app which I want to publish.

```
This App Bundle contains Java / Kotlin code, which can be deobfused. We recommend uploading a deobfuscation file for easier analysis and resolution of your crashes and ANRs.
```

And

```
This App Bundle contains native code and you have not uploaded any debugging symbols. We recommend uploading a symbol file so that your crashes and ANRs can be more easily analyzed and resolved
```

[answers says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749162/android-version-release-warning-message-this-app-bundle-contains-java-kotlin-co) first one can be fixed by adding `minifyEnabled true` &  `shrinkResources true` to this part of the `build.gradle` file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

for second warning: according to [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en) gradle plugin version should be `4.1` and above and my app having proper version, also as per [this doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#native-crash-support) I have installed `ndk (side by side)` and added

```
android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = { SYMBOL_TABLE }
```

in gradle file as well and still I am getting those warnings while uploading the app to the playstore.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: just a warning nothing else by the this link will help you out https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I have already seen this link but thank  you